# Way to deploy to another branch using Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: python, deployment, bitbucket, production, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a project that uses React and Python, it has 3 branches (`Development`, `Master` and `Production`). I want to make that the `Production` branch has the built version (all the virtualenv, React built, etc.).
I want to know if the bitbucket-pipeline can build the React and install the `pip install` the packages into a folder and send to the branch `Production` every time that i commit to the branch `master`.

Comment: Process *what* information? Your question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't explained well, when i mean process, is to build the react, install the pip packages in a folder, etc... The point is that i wanted to have a branch with the react builded and the python packages installed (in a folder, using virtualenv), i will correct my question.

Comment: Typically you wouldn't store that as a *branch*, that's for source code. If you want to store artifacts for deployment, there are tools specifically for that.